# what is the path of block/template from where images are being shown in mini cart?

Tags: cart

In my modules minicart this is code outputting images and remove, etc buttons.

```
 <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
 <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Corresponding block is `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar` and helper `$this->helper('ultimo');`. But I don't see `getItemHtml()` function present either in block file or the helper file. What is the exact path from where actual image is being outputted?

Comment: Enable template hints, you'll get the path of file from where those images are being displayed

Comment: Are you using the "Ultimo - Fluid Responsive Magento Theme"?

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis: Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you propably have a custom module with the alias "ultimo" as this is not a magento core module name.

That said,

```
Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Minicart

Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Minicart extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Abstract
```

The latter has a getItemHtml function near line 171 (Magento CE 1.9.2)

-- Edit --

As I said before, you are using a custom module so it should override the default template.

If not, the template is given in the construct function of `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar`.

```
$this->addItemRender('default', 'checkout/cart_item_renderer', 'checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml');
```

This means that the file you should be looking for is

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml
```

or

```
app/design/frontend/PACKAGE_NAME/TEMPLATE_NAME/template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml
```

Comment: thanks. function is present in Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Abstract block but it's like `public function getItemHtml(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item)
    {
        $renderer = $this->getItemRenderer($item->getProductType())->setItem($item);
        return $renderer->toHtml();
    }` . Where is the actual template where something like `<img src=` is present

Comment: Updated answer. Checkit out. Pretty sure your default template is overriden though

Comment: thanks. It's present in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml`

Answer (score 1):

Function `getItemHtml()` is in file 
**/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Abstract.php** 
that is extend by **/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Minicart.php** 
& this is extand by **/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php**

Comment: thanks. function is present in Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Abstract block but it's like `public function getItemHtml(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item)
    {
        $renderer = $this->getItemRenderer($item->getProductType())->setItem($item);
        return $renderer->toHtml();
    }` . Where is the actual template where something like `<img src=` is present

Answer (score -1):

The Method getItemHtml() :Get item row html;

such as：url://[ip]/sales/order/view/order_id/18/

xml:sales_order_view.xml >search code:

```
  <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View" name="sales.order.view" cacheable="false" after="sales.order.info.links">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Items" name="order_items" template="Magento_Sales::order/items.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="sales.order.items.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="sales_order_item_pager"/>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="4" class="mark"</argument>
                        <argument name="value_properties" xsi:type="string">class="amount"</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax" name="tax" template="Magento_Tax::order/tax.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
   </block>
```

template:items.phtml

```
 <?php $items = $block->getItems(); ?>
 <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
 <?php echo $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

The Html in /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/items/renderer/default.phtml;